# Id usage between two .qml files in Qt

Tags: qt, qml

How to use an rectangle id from one .qml file to another .qml file ?
Can you please help me with this ?

----cp.qml

```
Rectangle { id:PanelOne
width: parent.width
height: parent.height
anchors.centerIn: parent
color: "transparent"
    }
```

------lp.qml

*

```
Image {
            id: zoomOut
            source: "qrc:/zoomOut.png"
            MouseArea {
                onClicked: {
                    if (PanelOne.scale > 1.1)
                        PanelOne.scale -= zoom_offset
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can't directly do this. It is called encapsulation. You can use a property or alias.

Comment: Prepare a [mcve] and be more specific.

Comment: where in `lp` do you use `cp`?

Comment: That is exactly my question . How to use cp in lp ?   :D

Comment: as simple as `cp {}`

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Using ids from other QML files is not recommended. It makes your application hard to reason about, and thus very hard to debug or otherwise maintain. Also, such lookups are slow, as a deep tree will have to be searched for them. They will only work up to a point, adding an element of surprise.

Best practice is to keep the usage of ids local within the QML file. All other data should be shared between components by explicitly setting properties or by using controller components from C++.